# How to parse a JSON array of objects in C#

Tags: c#, json

```
{
   "jsonstring": [

  {
     "id":"01",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },

  {
     "id":"07",
     "language": "C++",
     "edition": "second",
     "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
  }


   ]
}
```

getting the post request like this how to parse this.

Comment: Googling for "How to parse a JSON array of objects in C#"  returns a *lot* of answers. Have you tried anything? Json.NET may be the most popular parser but it's not the only one

Comment: Specific Questions should be asked on this forum. Generic questions like this can easily be found on google

Answer (score 11):

Use [NewtonSoft.NET](http://newtonsoft.net/):

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Maybe make a corresponding class for using generics too:

```
public class ClassName {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string edition { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
}
```

then you can do:

```
List<ClassName> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClassName>>(json);
```

Comment: add one more info, you can use tools directly to generate classes from json, here is what I used http://jsonutils.com

Comment: @ShijoJohny Be sure to check out the below answer which doesn't have any external dependencies!

Answer (score 1):

In .NET you can use JavaScriptSerializer. First you will need to create a class that has the same structure as the json string.

Example:

```
{
    "Id":"07",
    "Language": "C++"
}


public class CSharpObject
{
    int Id {get; set;}
    string Language {get; set;}
}


string json = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(jsonString);
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
CSharpObject csharpObject = (CSharpObject)json_serializer.Deserialize<CSharpObject>(json);
```

Comment: Awesome, no need for external libraries!