# How to convert js-object to json via C#?

Tags: c#, json

I get a js-object as a string like this:

`var DATA = [{caseName: "MSP_INT_1",...},{...},...,]`

and there is my problem: there is any way to convert this string into json format (like this:

`{"caseName":...`)?

Comment: Are you saying you have a `string` with the content being `var DATA = ..` ?  If so, WHY are you getting that content?

Comment: Go to https://app.quicktype.io, paste your json string and get the C# counterpart code.

Comment: Hello, Please explain in detail. do you want convert JSON array objects to individual json objects?

Comment: @Ratheesh, yes, its a goal

Comment: @СемёнКазанцев Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766280/how-to-parse-a-json-array-of-objects-in-c-sharp/38766303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various JSON libraries present over the internet like org.json  or Newtonsoft.Json etc.

Using org.json library:

> JSONObject jsonObj = new
>   JSONObject("{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}");