# JSON Encode giving me invalid JSON file in PHP - generated from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to generate a JSON file for a unity game to read. I use C# to call the PHP file where I use a MYSQL query to get the relevant information from my database. I am getting the content I want but when I encode as a JSON file it is unreadable. I can see what is happening but I don't know how to fix! I am getting }{ after each record when encoding happens. This is the relevant bit of code in my php file (I think)

```
$sqlnew = "SELECT DISTINCT
   content.ContentTitle,
   content.ContentBody,
   user_habits.value,
  user_habits.boolean,
  users.User_ID

FROM user_habits
       INNER JOIN users
         ON user_habits.user_id = users.User_ID,
     content_habitparameters
       INNER JOIN content
         ON content_habitparameters.Content_ID = content.Content_ID
WHERE users.User_ID = 1
AND ((user_habits.value >= content_habitparameters.Min_Value
and user_habits.value <= content_habitparameters.Max_Value)
OR user_habits.boolean = content_habitparameters.Boolean)";

$result = $conn->query($sqlnew);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
   $dbdata = array();
}
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$dbdata[]=$row;
}

//print array in JSON format
echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

My SQL result looks like this:

- ContentTitle: Average Daily Cigarettes - ContentBody: Smoking cigarettes creates a link between e.g. Being on the phone and smoking. You need to break these habits to succeed. Be aware of when you tend to reach for a fag and think of alternatives for those situations. - value: 30 - user_habits.boolean: - users.User_ID: 1 users.Username lz7cjc
- ContentTitle: Fight one big temptation to avoid lots of smaller ones - ContentBody: Give yourself the best chance of success by removing all smoking related items from your house, the car, work and anywhere else you spend time. Avoid buying tobacco products and it will be much harder to give in to a temptation. Behaviour change is not just about will power. It is also about how easy it is to stop or start doing something. Make it hard to smoke and it will be easier to resist temptation - value: - user

when I encode into a JSON file I get this:

```
[  {"ContentTitle":"Average Daily Cigarettes",
    "ContentBody":"Smoking cigarettes creates a link between e.g. Being on the phone and smoking. You need to break these habits to succeed. Be aware of when you tend to reach for a fag and think of alternatives for those situations.",
    "value":"30",
    "boolean":null,
    "User_ID":"1",
    "Username":"lz7cjc"
   },{
    "ContentTitle":"Fight one big temptation to avoid lots of smaller ones",
    "ContentBody":"Give yourself the best chance of success by removing all smoking related items from your house, the car, work and anywhere else you spend time. Avoid buying tobacco products and it will be much harder to give in to a temptation. Behaviour change is not just about will power. It is also about how easy it is to stop or start doing something. Make it hard to smoke and it will be easier to resist temptation\r\n",
    "value":null,
    "boolean":"1",
    "User_ID":"1",
    "Username":"lz7cjc"
  },{
```

And obviously I can't read that in unity. I guess one way to solve is to create multiple JSON files but that is clunky even for me.

Help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to convert JSON String to C# Object? Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38766303/12397250)

Comment: If this JSON isn't the result/format that you want, you should show us the format that you _do_ want.

Comment: Why cant you read it, does Unity not understand JSON? Does it fail to convert it to a Unity data structure?

Comment: Is that the ACTUAL JSON or did you just summarise it, I ask as, as it stands of course it not valid JSON

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

Comment: Did you just forget to convert what looks like a blob of text (JSON) into something usable for your environment?

Comment: @PatrickQ - it was the first two records. The format I want is a readable format so i guess no {} in the middle of the file which looks like are being used to seperate the records

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes unity supports JSON and thanks for the link - unfortunately that doesn't help as the problem is with the way PHP is generating the JSON. I can handle it in c# for Unity once I get the format correct

Comment: @VincentJonathan thanks - will take a closer look

Comment: You do realise that what you show IS VALID JSON, a JSON Array or objects in fact. Once you convert that to a usable data type, in Unity, you will have to process it like an array of objects and not just a BLOB of text

Comment: @lz7cjc  You still haven't specified exactly what you consider a "readable format" to be.  Are you only wanting one record?  JSON is JSON, there are not multiple formats of it.  PHP will only generate valid JSON when using `json_encode()`.  So if the output is not what you want, it is unclear what you _do_ want.

Comment: How comes `Username` is in the result but not in the SELECT clause?

Comment: thanks all - the problem appears to be with using the data in Unity and the solution is beyond me. So will see how i can close this question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well your json_encoding an array which may be referred to as a List with arrays that could be referred to as Maps.

For instance you pass into the function an array like this:

```
array( // this is a List, you have only object
 array( // this is a Map, you have key value pairs
  'Content-Title' => ...,
  'ContentBody'   => ...,
 ),
 array( // this is a Map, you have key value pairs
  'Content-Title'=>...,
  'ContentBody'   => ...,
 ),
)
```

encoded this adds a [ ] at the endings to indicate it is a List.

```
[{...}{...}]
```

If you want to have a map / json object you have to specify keys when adding results and call those keys in you C# script.

```
$count = 1;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
 $dbdata["result-$count"] = $row;
 $count++;
}
```

this will in turn give you an array like:

```
array( // this is a Map, you have key value pairs
'result-1' => array( // this is a Map, you have key value pairs
  'Content-Title' => ...,
  'ContentBody'   => ...,
 ),
'result-2' => array( // this is a Map, you have key value pairs
  'Content-Title'=>...,
  'ContentBody'   => ...,
 ),
)
```

which should result in an encoding like:

```
{"result-1":{...},"result-2":{...}}
```

Edit: 
Some languages have Maps and Lists as separate data types C# has them separate. While in PHP an array has the function of both.

A map in general as the name suggests is a construct that MAPS out values with the help of user specified keys.

```
$map = array(
 'this_key'                           => 'will_give_me_this_result',
 'and_this_one'                       => 'will_give_me_value_at_this_key',
 'I_help_you_find_whats_on_the_right' => ' \0/" ',
);
```

While a list doesn't necessary use keys to point to values. You can use indexes 0,1.. they have the function of keys but still wouldn't be considered keys since they specify the position of the value and don't need to be explicitly set.

```
$list = array(
 'IM at position 0',
 "and Im at 1, but hey you don't need me to tell you this, I'll always be here",
 "position 2, well unless you manipulate me bastard",
 array(
  'let me be clear',
  'my parent is still just a value of outer most array',
  "you still now the position of it"
 )
);
```

Now, if we json_encoded these two arrays:

1. array / $map

```
{"this_key":"will_give_me_this_result","and_this_one":"will_give_me_value_at_this_key","I_help_you_find_whats_on_the_right":" \\0\/\" "}
```

2. array / $list

```
["IM at position 0","and Im at 1, but hey you don't need me to tell you this, I'll always be here","position 2, well unless you manipulate me bastard",["let me be clear","my parent is still just a value of the outer most array","you still now the position of it"]]
```

Notice the different brackets?

The [ ] indicate the objects inside are in a predictable 0,1,2 order, they don't need keys to specify them.

On the other hand { } specify a map. You can see that there are  multiple "key_key" : "value_value" occurrences. Well that's because you need keys to know what value is what.

Now, I personally don't know C# and how to decode json in that particular language so I went on a hunch that you want to get some kind of key:value result and you couldn't because your json output indicates a List not a Map.

Here are the arrays in json_encoding but spaces added for visibility.

1. array / $map

```
{
 "this_key":"will_give_me_this_result",
 "and_this_one":"will_give_me_value_at_this_key",
 "I_help_you_find_whats_on_the_right":" \\0\/\" "
}
```

2. array / $list

```
[
  "IM at position 0",
  "and Im at 1, but hey you don't need me to tell you this, I'll always be here",
  "position 2, well unless you manipulate me bastard",
 [
   "let me be clear",
   "my parent is still just a value of the outer most array",
   "you still now the position of it"
 ]
]
```

Comment: thanks for this - sounds complicated and will take me some time but will give it a go

Comment: this was basically the problem as Unity couldn't recognise the additional levels i had created. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

if you are using PDO, try:

`$dbdata = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($dbdata);`

This fetches the result as php array.
That should not create an invalid json.

Comment: WHat the OP did should not create invalid JSON

Comment: thanks - I assume that replaces    $dbdata = array(); 
but when i try it i get an error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll()

Comment: @lz7cjc seems like you are using mysqli not the PDO, all right so forget my solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

so it wasn't the JSON file/XML it was Unity being unable to handle the data. Thanks to everyone who pointed this out.

This is a truncated view of what has been successfully implemented:

```
{
PlayerTipsJSON loadedPlayerData = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerTipsJSON>(json);
for (int i = 0;i<loadedPlayerData.data.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(loadedPlayerData.data[i].User_ID + "\n");
            Debug.Log(loadedPlayerData.data[i].ContentTitle + "\n");
            Debug.Log(loadedPlayerData.data[i].ContentBody+ "\n");
            Debug.Log(loadedPlayerData.data[i].value + "\n");
            Debug.Log(loadedPlayerData.data[i].boolean + "\n");
        }
}
[System.Serializable]
    public class PlayerData
    {
        public string fromJSONusername;
        public string ContentTitle;
        public string ContentBody;
        public int User_ID;
        public int value;
        public bool boolean;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class PlayerTipsJSON
    {
        public List<PlayerData> data;
    }
```

I haven't commented the code as I didn't write it and to be honest not 100% sure what is going on! I think it is an array of an array.